# unix shell: check file list in dir versus with list of files from a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I am trying to write a sh script to check check that all files from list of files' extentions stored in a file are in a place in a particular dir. I am doing following:

file names looks like yyyymmdd.ext

hoff_list.lst sample is following:

```
abc
dfg
hij
klm
xxx
...
```

my script is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
_input="/exchange/hoff_list.lst"
hoffdate="20130328"
hsourcedir="/upload_data/"
while IFS=' \t\n' read -r line; do
echo "=$line=" #first problem there
hoff_name=$hsourcedir$hoffdate"."$line
  if test ! "$hoff_name"
     then echo "$hoff_name DOES exist"
     else echo "$hoff_name does NOT exist or is empty"
  fi
done < "$_input"
```

but it doesnt revert relevant reply. It doesnt find a file if the file is reqly exists in dir.
     echo "=$line="

reterns

```
=abc
=dfg
...
```

when expected

```
=abc=
=dfg=
...
```

looks problem is there, but haven't a clue how to handle it. Will appreciate your help there...

Comment: If you are checking that a file exists, I miss a `if [ -f $hoff_name  ]` line.

Comment: try echo "=${line}=" – golimar 7 mins ago
the same:
=abc
=dfg
...

Answer (score 1):

The file `/exchange/hoff_list.lst` has CRLF line endings http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.

Get rid of CR.  You can try using the `dos2unix` utility available on most Linux systems or refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities.